# Cohomology of an intermediate extension (perverse) sheaf on the affine line

Tags: perverse-sheaves, constructible-sheaves

Let $\mathbb{A}^1$ be defined over a finite field or $\mathbb{C}$, $j: \mathbb{G}_m \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^1$ and $\mathcal{F}$ a local system on $\mathbb{G}_m$. I wonder what is known about the cohomology (i.e. cohomology with respect to the standard t-structure) of the intermediate extension sheaf $j_{!*} \mathcal{F}$.

I know for example for any perverse sheaf $\mathcal{G}$ on $\mathbb{A}^1$ 'with singularity in 0':

- $H^{n}(\mathcal{G})= 0$ if n $\neq$ -1,0
- $H^{0}(\mathcal{G})$ is supported in 0
- $H^{-1}(\mathcal{G})$ has no sections supported in 0

Q1: Does this already imply that $H^{0}(j_{!*} \mathcal{F})=0$? What else is known about $H^{n}(j_{!*} \mathcal{F})$?

Consider the epimorphism

$j_! \mathcal{F} \twoheadrightarrow j_{!*} \mathcal{F}$

in $Perv(\mathbb{A}^1)$.

Q2: Is anything known about $H^0$ and $H^1$ of this epimorphism? I.e. does it induce an epimorphism on $H^0$ or $H^1$?